# Jech 3.1: Isomorphism theorem

Tags: set-theory

Jech's Theorem 3.1 states:

> **Theorem 3.1** (Isomorphism theorem): If $\mathcal M \vDash \text{Extensionality}$, then $\mathcal M$ is isomorphic to a transitive class.

The proof begins with:

> It is easy to see that if $\phi(\vec x)$ is a formula without quantifiers, then it is true in a transitive model $\mathcal M$ iff it is true in the universe.

I do not know what this means:

1. What does it mean for $\phi(\vec x)$ to be "true in the universe"? The best that I could come up with was to say that $\phi(x)$ must hold *outside* the model $M$, in the "universe of mathematical discourse" we are studying $\mathcal M$ in.
2. How does one prove the reverse direction? If $\phi$ is true in the universe, why must it be true of $\mathcal M$?

Comment: Re: 1, your interpretation is correct; precisely, we're proving "For all quantifier-free $\varphi$ and all transitive $\mathcal{M}$, we have $\varphi\leftrightarrow\varphi^\mathcal{M}$." (Note that since the complexity of $\varphi$ is bounded this is actually an expressible claim - Tarski's undefinability theorem would only bite us if we tried to write something like "For all $\varphi$ *of any complexity* [stuff].") Re: (2), have you tried induction on complexity?